# Having hard time with image separator in HTML/CSS

Tags: css, web, html

I am creating a basic website. I want to use a horizontal separator image between two sections of my webpage. It is not showing up right now. This is the HTML that I have used:

```
<hr class="separator">
<div class="separator"></div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
hr.largeseparator {
    border: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("divider2.png");
    }

largeseparator {
    border: 0;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("divider2.png");
}
```

The file is in the same folder as my HTML file.

Here is the actual HTML that I am using:

```css
hr.largeseparator {
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: url("divider2.png");
}
```

```html
<h2> Lorem ipsum dolor </h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi consectetur sapien magna, id malesuada neque blandit ut. Suspendisse ut purus sit amet sem varius luctus sagittis a arcu. Ut id massa ut dui ultrices maximus. Nam non pulvinar lectus, ut viverra
  dui. Praesent ut turpis at libero consectetur imperdiet in ut metus. Donec condimentum ullamcorper sapien non sagittis. Etiam ut condimentum dolor. Nunc lacus ante, tempor sed posuere finibus, ornare sed augue</p>
</div>
<hr class="largeseparator">
<div id="Text2">
  <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor </h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi consectetur sapien magna, id malesuada neque blandit ut. Suspendisse ut purus sit amet sem varius luctus sagittis a arcu. Ut id massa ut dui ultrices maximus. Nam non pulvinar lectus, ut
    viverra dui. Praesent ut turpis at libero consectetur imperdiet in ut metus. Donec condimentum ullamcorper sapien non sagittis. Etiam ut condimentum dolor. Nunc lacus ante, tempor sed posuere finibus, ornare sed augue</p>
```

Comment: Do not add elements whose sole purpose is to be a separator. That's what margin is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with your css , but you might need `background-size` and eventually reset `background-repeat`

```css
hr.largeseparator {
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: url("http://www.fblakeside.net/hp_wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/divider-1024x119.png") center;
  background-size: auto 100%
}

hr.no-repeat {
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor </h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi consectetur sapien magna, id malesuada neque blandit ut. Suspendisse ut purus sit amet sem varius luctus sagittis a arcu. Ut id massa ut dui ultrices maximus. Nam non pulvinar lectus, ut
    viverra dui. Praesent ut turpis at libero consectetur imperdiet in ut metus. Donec condimentum ullamcorper sapien non sagittis. Etiam ut condimentum dolor. Nunc lacus ante, tempor sed posuere finibus, ornare sed augue</p>
</div>
<hr class="largeseparator" />
<div id="Text2">
  <h2> No repeat separator </h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi consectetur sapien magna, id malesuada neque blandit ut. Suspendisse ut purus sit amet sem varius luctus sagittis a arcu. Ut id massa ut dui ultrices maximus. Nam non pulvinar lectus, ut
    viverra dui. Praesent ut turpis at libero consectetur imperdiet in ut metus. Donec condimentum ullamcorper sapien non sagittis. Etiam ut condimentum dolor. Nunc lacus ante, tempor sed posuere finibus, ornare sed augue</p>
  <hr class="largeseparator no-repeat" />
```

The path to the image is to be think from the path where stands the CSS file.

Your CSS looks for divider.png in the folder where stands your CSS.

You might also have to mind urlrewriting if your site uses it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!  It is strange that with some files is working and with some not. But everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected verify the source of your image..

```css
hr.largeseparator {
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/350x150");
}
```

```html
<h2> Lorem ipsum dolor </h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi consectetur sapien magna, id malesuada neque blandit ut. Suspendisse ut purus sit amet sem varius luctus sagittis a arcu. Ut id massa ut dui ultrices maximus. Nam non pulvinar lectus, ut viverra
  dui. Praesent ut turpis at libero consectetur imperdiet in ut metus. Donec condimentum ullamcorper sapien non sagittis. Etiam ut condimentum dolor. Nunc lacus ante, tempor sed posuere finibus, ornare sed augue</p>
</div>
<hr class="largeseparator">
<div id="Text2">
  <h2> Lorem ipsum dolor </h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi consectetur sapien magna, id malesuada neque blandit ut. Suspendisse ut purus sit amet sem varius luctus sagittis a arcu. Ut id massa ut dui ultrices maximus. Nam non pulvinar lectus, ut
    viverra dui. Praesent ut turpis at libero consectetur imperdiet in ut metus. Donec condimentum ullamcorper sapien non sagittis. Etiam ut condimentum dolor. Nunc lacus ante, tempor sed posuere finibus, ornare sed augue</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Think I made it.